# P/Invoke Unmanaged Pointer, as IntPtr or as void*

Tags: pinvoke

I have an unmanaged code with a fixed struct in memory, i need to read and write the struct from the managed side; the application is a real-time application and i cannot afford the struct's marshalling every time i need it, so i think is better to work in an unsafe context(for performance) and directy handle the pointer.
If i have this signature:

```
public static extern IntPtr COLM104_GetGlobalConf();
```

and my pointer is a `RuntimeDescriptor*`, can i store directly store the `RuntimeDescriptor*` as an object's field or i must keep the pointer in an IntPtr and every time i need it i should do:

```
(RuntimeDescriptor*)pointerField.ToPointer()
```

and last thing, can i directly change the p/invoke signature with:

```
public static extern RuntimeDescriptor* COLM104_GetGlobalConf();
```

Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: It is okayish.  Critical that you get the layout of the managed declaration for the struct completely identical to the unmanaged version of it.  Accidents happen, you'll find out quick enough.  Casting an IntPtr doesn't otherwise make it safer.

Comment: Yes, i already figured out about the struct layout, i'm keeping maximum attention to everything come in my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare an unsafe member of type `RuntimeDescriptor*`. And you can declare the return value of your p/invoke to be of type `RuntimeDescriptor*`.

However, it doesn't really gain you any performance over a cast to `RuntimeDescriptor*`. Certainly with optimisations enabled, the compiler doesn't need to emit any actual code to perform the cast. However, if you are going down the route of using unsafe code then it's cleaner to be all-in. Declaring the member and return type to be `RuntimeDescriptor*` makes your program easier to read.

FWIW, there's no need for the call `ToPointer()` in the code in your question. You can write that cast like this:

```
(RuntimeDescriptor*)pointerField
```

Comment: i will follow your suggestions